# Git automatically merge from depending branches

Tags: git, merge, branch

We work with features branches. Our workflow is just simple: we never make changes on master, all work is done in either feature- or bugfix branches. We  `merge no-ff` only between branches and `pull --ff-only` from remote repository. We have only one remote repository were we push all our branches.

Sometimes a feature introduced in one feature branch is also needed in another one. Thats why we do merge between branches. On long running branches it is possible to forget that a branch was onced merged with another one.

The question: is it possible to add something like an git alias to automatically merge from depending branches, like `git add-dependencies` to add such a depended feature branch, and `git merge-dependencies` to have those octopused merged?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to  accomplish. You have a branch A that was branched off of master; you make commits C1, C2 and C3 on A. Then you create branch B off of A, and make commits C4, C5 and C6. When you merge B into master, you're merging in C1 to C6, not just C4 to C6. So it seems like the dependent commits, C1 to C3, get merged in. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @DanFischer

E.g I have a branch `A` branched of from `master`, and a colleague  of mine starts with branch `B`, branched of from `master` as well. He introduces one `enum` type in `C1`. I am interested in this `enum` in my branch and merge `C1` in to `A`, thus generating `C2`.

Now I consider my branch `A` depending on branch `B`. If my colleague creates `C3`, possibly does some changes on this `enum`-type on his branch I would like to know of his change he made. Since I might forget that I consider my branch depending on `B` I´d like to have some auto tracking help.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  That's an interesting idea.  I'm pretty sure the only way to "depend" on another branch is to "track" it, and a branch can only track a single branch.  So I think your best bet is to write a script or scripts yourself to accomplish what you're looking for.  And, if you didn't already know, you can create git aliases:  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases